# Google Chrome Search Bar Text Upside Down

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know really how to ask this as a question because I'm not sure what is going on: in my Google Chrome browser the search bar's text is upside down when I try to type in it or click on it, everything else on the page is the proper way and when I click off the search bar the text goes back to normal. Is there something that I may have done to have this happen? It just started today and it is really really annoying. The only inference I have seen about this happening to someone else was on here: http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/336245/ and although several people claimed to have a similar problem that started occuring this week no one has been able to solve it

[image: example]

Answer (score 9):

Go into your Chrome **Settings** > **Advanced Settings** > un-check **Use hardware acceleration when available**.

Not sure why but it fixed my issue. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just saw this and was about to do it and now before I had the chance to try this the search bar is back to normal! I have no clue why it happened but if it does again I will try your suggestion. thanks

Comment: Ive also got this issue, but thought it was due to my trackpad freaking out. Will try your suggestion

Comment: Just to confirm, this just happened on a computer in my household as well.   The text was also upside down in the find box. This is on a Mac OS10.10 Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit). The above suggestion worked... still trying to find out why. Anyone?

Comment: Just found this current thread, we could keep our eye on it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479097

Comment: Good looking out @John Shipp I will watch that thread for updates

Comment: Update: I reviewed this thread again, and, it appears as though from v43.+ this issue has been fixed. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479097 ... so, to fix this issue, update chrome to the latest version (v43.+).